# Java Script Accordion Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an accordion for each row of a an html table using the following script

**HTML**

```
<table class="list" id="table" data-bind="visible: !loading()">
    @*<table class="productTable" data-bind="sortTable:true">*@
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Term</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Pipeline</th>
            <th>Bid C/P</th>
            <th>Bid Volume</th>
            <th>Index</th>

            <th>Bid</th>
            <th>Offer</th>
            <th>Offer Volume</th>
            <th>Offer C/P</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: canadiancrudes" >
        <tr class="accordion">
            <td data-bind="text:Product"></td>
        </tr>

               <tr class="" data-bind="template: { name: $root.displayMode, data: $data }"></tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

**2. Java Script**

```
$(function () {
        var $list = $('.list');
        $list.find("tr").not('.accordion').hide();
        $list.find("tr").eq(0).show();
        $list.find(".accordion").click(function () {
            $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
            $list.find('.accordion').not(this).siblings().fadeOut(500);
            $(this).siblings().fadeToggle(500);
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $list.find('.accordion').not(this).removeClass('active');
            $list.find('.accordion').not(this).css("opacity", 0.33);
            $list.find('.accordion').not(this).hover(function () {
                $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
            },
                function () {
                    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.33);
                });
        });
    });
```

**CSS**

```
#table tbody .accordion:hover td:first-child, #table tbody .accordion.active td:first-child{ 
    border-left:3px solid #000; float:left;  overflow: hidden; padding-left: 5px; width:100%;
            }
.active{opacity:1!important;}
#table tbody tr td{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

And for reasons my accordion is not working with the above code.
May I know where exactly I am making mistake.

Comment: Where is the element with `class="list"`?

Comment: why aren't you using the jquery ui accordion widget?

Comment: @Andy.. Sorry thats a kind of typo. I have edited the question, still the same result.

Comment: Accordians are easy enough to do without the resource hog of jQueryUI, @RubenVerschueren.

Comment: I'll admit I'm confused what you're trying to do here tho. Like the answerer said, accordians are best with divs. If you click on an accordion row in a table it will disappear and you won't be able to view it again by clicking on it. Accordions have headers that you click on to expand to see the content. Once you click on a heading, all the other contents collapse, but not the headings.

Comment: @Andy.. But it seems html5 doesn't allow me to use divs within tbody.

Comment: @Andy When the script in the following jsfiddle works fine, then why not mine ..http://jsfiddle.net/alok108/EfeTN/40/

Comment: What's the difference between your source code and the jsfiddle? That'll be the answer.

Comment: @Andy.. Well, I dint find much differences except that I am using knock out Js for binding the data and SignalR framework for some real time interaction along with knockout Js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it my self using  tag. but its not too friendly with SignalR though.
Code is as follows

```
<table class="list" id="table" data-bind="visible: !loading()">

    <thead>

        <tr>

            <th>Term</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Pipeline</th>
            <th>Bid C/P</th>
            <th>Bid Volume</th>
            <th>Index</th>

            <th>Bid</th>
            <th>Offer</th>
            <th>Offer Volume</th>
            <th>Offer C/P</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
      <!--ko foreach: canadiancrudes-->
    <tbody class="" >
        <tr class="accordion">
            <td colspan="14" data-bind="text:Product"></td>
        </tr>

               <tr class=""  data-bind="template: { name: $root.displayMode, data: $data }"></tr>


    </tbody>
    <!--/ko-->

    <tfoot>
        <tr>

            <th>Term</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Pipeline</th>
            <th>Bid C/P</th>
            <th>Bid Volume</th>
            <th>Index</th>

            <th>Bid</th>
            <th>Offer</th>
            <th>Offer Volume</th>
            <th>Offer C/P</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant hide and show table row's you'd have to convert it into either lists or div's.